# Returning two elements on a filter return Pandoc-filter

Tags: javascript, pandoc

filter-node.
I am trying to add a line break before I return a Header element

```
 if (type === "Header") {
    return [LineBreak(),Header(value[0], value[1], value[2])];
 }
```

I get a mempty error on the LineBreak return.
Any ideas how I can accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [pandoc AST definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types/docs/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html#t:Block), which is linked to in the [filter tutorial](http://pandoc.org/filters.html), you can see that an element is always a `Block` or an `Inline`.

Specifically, a `LineBreak` is of type `Inline`. Thus you need to wrap it in a `Para` or `Plain` to make it a `Block`.

I don't know the js lib you're using, but along the lines of:

```
return [
  Para([ LineBreak() ]),
  Header(value[0], value[1], value[2])
]);
```